# Compactness of $ Lu = -\partial_x^2 u + u $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compact-operators

I am trying to apply the spectral theorem to the operator:
$$Lu = -\partial_x^2u + u $$
in $L^2([0,1])$ with domain $D(L)=\{u\in H^2([0,1]) s.t. \partial_xu(0)=\partial_xu(1)=0\}$.
I need to prove that $L$ is self-adjoint and compact. For the first point, denote $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the standard inner product in $L^2$ and let $u,v\in D(L)$:
$$
\langle Lu,v\rangle = \int_0^1 (-\partial_x^2u)v + uv = \int_0^1 u(-\partial_x^2v) +uv = \langle u,Lv\rangle. 
$$
Now for the compactness, I am no certain about my argument. Here is the definition of compact operator I have:

> A bounded linear operator $K:X\rightarrow Y$ ($X,Y$ Banach spaces) is
> called  compact if for any bounded sequence $(u_k)_k$ in $X$, there
> exists a subsequence such that $\bigl(Ku_{\phi(k)}\bigr)_k$ converges
> in $Y$.

In my case, $X=D(L)$ with the norm $\lVert u\rVert_{H^2}$, $Y=L^2([0,1])$. Thanks to the Reilich-Kondrachov theorem, the embedding $H^2([0,1])\subset L^2([0,1])$ is compact.
Then I use the fact that $L$ is continuous, i.e. $\forall u\in D(L)$:
$$
\lVert Lu\rVert_{L^2}^2=\int_0^1\lvert -\partial_x^2 u + u \rvert^2 \leq \lVert u \rVert^2_{H^2}
$$
to show that $\forall (u_k)_k$ bounded in $D(L)$, $\exists (u_{\phi(k)})_k$ converging in $L^2$ (compact embedding) and by continuity $Lu_{\phi(n)}$ converges in $L^2$.

Is my proof correct? In particular, I am always confused by which norm I should use at each step. Thank you.

Comment: There are some problems I can see. Firstly, the spectral theorem for compact operators is a statement about diagonalizing compact operators mapping a (separable) hilbert space to *itself*. The operator you wrote down would be viewed from the perspective of spectral theory on Hilbert spaces as an unbounded operator acting on a dense subspace. Normally this is tackled by showing the resolvent is compact at some real energy, then use the spectral theorem on that. iirc this operator is not even self adj. due to the boundary conditions. Checking this is more delicate, what you checked is symmetry.

Comment: Also, the argument using Rellich-Kondrachov seems flawed: you extracted an $L^2 $convergent subsequence using the theorem, and then concluded by continuity of L on *$H^2$* that you have convergence. Do you see the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your proof is correct, let's just walk real quick through the steps and the norm you are using:

Remember to show the operator $L$ is compact you want to show that if $\{u_k\}_{k}$ is bounded in the domain (here $X$ which has the $H^2$ norm) then you want to show that within $\{Lu_k\}_k$ has a convergent subsequence, convergent *in its own space* which is $Y$ with the $L^2$ norm. Since as you said by the Reilich-Kondrachov theorem, the embedding $H^{2}([0,1])⊂L^{2}([0,1])$ is compact, then the boundedness of $\{u_k\}_k$ in the $H^2$ norm is sufficient to show that $\{Lu_k\}_k$ has a convergent subsequence in the $L^2$ norm, thus your operator $L$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you very much. As a follow-up question, I am asked to solve the problem $Lu = \cos(\pi x) + \frac23 \cos(5\pi x)$ with the homogeneous neumann boundary conditions from before. I was thinking expressing the cos functions as a serie with general term $\langle cos,\phi_n\rangle\phi_n(x)$, where $\phi_n$ are the eigenvectors of $L$ (i.e. $\sin(\sqrt{1+(n\pi)^2}x)$), hoping the serie would reduce to a finite sum and I can identify coefficients. But I can't figure out the computations, so I wonder if my approach is correct.

Comment: I don't follow your last sentence. Rellich-Kondrachov allows you to extract an L^2 convergent subsequence of a sequence bounded in H^2, yes, but how does it let you extract one from L applied to this sequence, which then is just a bounded sequence in L^2?

Comment: The injection $j:H^2\rightarrow L^2$ is compact, so by definition if the subsequence $(u_{\phi(n)})_n$ is weakly convergent in $H^2$, $j((u_{\phi(n)}))_n$ converges strongly in $L^2$ towards $u$. Since $L$ is continuous, the convergence is preserved when applied to $u_{\phi(k)}$, I think?

Comment: @Rem That last sentence is the problem: it's continuous as a map from $H^2$ to $L^2$, meaning if $u_n\to u$ in $H^2$, then $Lu_n\to Lu$ in $L^2$, when you pass to this subsequence, you are applying $L$ to an $L^2$ convergent sequence, not $H^2$